# Aggregate columns containing dictionary in SQL presto

Tags: sql, presto

Hi I want to do SQL Presto query for the data table (say **user_data**) looks like

```
user | target | result
-----------------------------
 1   |    b   | {A: 1}
 2   |    a   | {C: 2}
 1   |    c   | {A: 2, B: 3}
 2   |    d   | {A: 1}
 1   |    d   | {C: 4}
```

With this data table, I would like to generate the following two outputs.

**Output 1:** Aggregate the values of the {key:value} dictionary based on the user and regardless of target

```
user | result
-------------------
  1  | {A:3, B:3, C:4}
  2  | {A:1, C:2}
```

**Output 2:** Aggregate the last column based on the targets of the user.

```
user | result
-------------------
  1  | {A:[b,c], B:[c], C:[d]}
  2  | {A:[d], C:[a]}
```

Can anyone help me with it? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Second one can be easily achieved with [`multimap_agg`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#multimap_agg) (add `transform_values` with `array_distinct` to remove duplicates if needed):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(user, target, result) AS (
 values (1, 'b',  map(array['A'], array[1])),
    (2, 'a',  map(array['C'], array[2])),
    (1, 'c',  map(array['A', 'B'], array[1, 2]))
)

-- query
select user, multimap_agg(k, target)
from dataset,
     unnest(result) as t (k,v)
group by user;
```

Output:

| user | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {A=[b, c], B=[c]} |
| 2 | {C=[a]} |

As for the first one - you can look into using [`map_union_sum`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#map_union_sum) if it is available in your version of Presto. Or use some magic with unnest and `transform_values`:

```sql
-- query
select user,
       transform_values(
               multimap_agg(k, v),
               (k,v) -> reduce(v, 0, (s, x) -> s + x, s -> s) -- or array_sum if available
           )
from dataset,
     unnest(result) as t (k, v)
group by user;
```

Output:

| user | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {A=2, B=2} |
| 2 | {C=2} |